# makefile error: “make: *** No rule to make target …”

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use GCC (linux) with a makefile to compile my project.
I get the following error

```
"No rule to make target 'output/src/main.o', needed by 'test'.  Stop."
```

This is the makefile:

```
COMPILE_PREX ?= 
CC = $(COMPILE_PREX)gcc

SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS = $(addprefix ./output/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCE)))

INCLUDES = -I ./src
CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall -g
LDFLAGS += -lpthread

TARGET = test

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p ./output
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(addprefix ./output/, $@) -c $< 

clean:
    rm -rf ./output
```

Comment: You are lying to make. The `%.o: %.c` rule does not create `$@` (which you promised), but `./output/$@` (which is the lie).

Comment: What should I do if I want to output the `*.o` to `./output/`?

Comment: Does changing the rule to `output/%.o: src/%.c` work? This also needs `$(CC) .... -o $@ -c $<`.

Comment: I'm trying, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does `output/src/%.o: src/%.c` or `output/%.o: %.c` work?

Comment: Ok, the next step on Stackoverflow would be to upvote and accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Note the use of `mkdir $(@D)` to create output directories as needed.

```
COMPILE_PREX ?=
CC = $(COMPILE_PREX)gcc

SOURCE = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJS = $(addprefix output/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCE)))

INCLUDES = -I src
CFLAGS += -O2 -Wall -g
LDFLAGS += -lpthread

TARGET = test

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)

output/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf output
```

Running it here with `make clean test`:

```
rm -rf output
gcc -O2 -Wall -g -I src -o output/src/hello.o -c src/hello.c
gcc output/src/hello.o -lpthread -o test
```